# ASP.NET Web API Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

I'm on a project and we are trying to add authorization for a document exposed via Web API. The document will be viewed using a link in another ASP.NET web application.

Is it possible to use Basic Authentication to secure the web API method and have the client send in the credentials of the user that is currently logged in to the ASP.NET web site when the link is clicked on the site? How can this be achieved?

The controller is not on the same site as the web application.

Comment: Did you look here? [ASP.NET WebApi Basic Authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication)

Comment: So long as the web API controller is part of the same web app as the site, it will use the same authentication.

Comment: The controller is not on the same site as the web application

Answer (score 0):

Put [Authorized] tag on every API Controller , which check login user.